# Why does nuget Bootstrapper use so many linked classes

Tags: visual-studio, architecture, nuget

I just recently came across the Visual Studio option to reference files as links. I think I groked the basic concept and also used it myself once. However, when I realized how nuget leverages this feature in the bootstrapper I found myself wondering what's the benefit in contrast to proper layering and referencing another assembly?

Can anyone point out the benefit of using linked classes against layering + referencing another assembly here?

[image: Nuget bootstrapper using linked classes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have less dependencies. The intent of the NuGet bootstrapper is to have the minimal amount of logic to bootstrap nuget.exe without having to duplicate alot of the code (that's why certain files are shared). In this particular case, we didn't want to have an unnecessary extra assembly, the nuget bootstrapper is a single exe.

Comment: Mmh. Isn't it just a single exe because it got ILMerged later on. It seems as if it's already layered into nuget.exe and Nuget.Core.dll which get merged later on.

Comment: The bootstrapper isn't ILMerged with anything. NuGet.exe is ILMerged with NuGet.Core.dll and it's huge (relatively). The bootstrapper has just enough code to do basic things (like download the latest version using the same logic nuget.core does).

Comment: Ok, so basically you did not want the bootstrapper to take a dependency on Nuget.Core.dll (and maybe ILMerge that to have a single bootstrapper exe) to keep the bootstrapper smaller in filesize. Ok, could be reasonable..just trying to familiar myself with the options that are available ;-)